# There is a course that teaches a specific version of the Jazz tune Summertime that I cannot find

Tags: jazz, learning-resources, lead-sheets

I'm searching for a version of summertime and the course that teaches it. Around 2005-2009 there was an online website that offered a course that contained a book with 4 dvds and different, progressively more complicated lead sheets teaching the George Gershwin song Summertime. The gentleman who narrated and played the piano on the DVDs had an interesting accent (pronouncing the word "root" like "rut") and may have been named "Bill".

I do not know what key it was written in, but the first chord was an F7 leading to a G7. The melody statrted on B then went to G for the first two quarter notes, then back to B.

The final chord was an Emin6. The first chord was an F7 on the first B, leading to a G7 when playing B the second time in the opening melody. There was an Amin7 following the first measure on the "fish are jumpin'" part, followed by some combination of a C min 7 and a C#min11th. It was an interesting harmonization and I would love to be able to learn it again now that I'm more musically mature.

Sadly, I cannot find the website nor the course it sold and every version of Summertime is harmonically different than this course. I have been searching without luck for weeks now, perhaps there are those here who have encountered this learning material and could share a link?

Comment: Hi @jazzpiano, welcome to SE MP&T! Sadly, this kind of questions, asking for recommendations are out of the scope of this site and will likely be closed…  Maybe having a look at https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask would be useful!

Comment: Hi @Tom, which part of my question falls under that "don't ask" list? My question is not about "participating in a discussion", I really would like others to explain where I can find this music. No part of my question or the answer to it is subjective, open-ended, a rant, or the like. This is definitely a "constructive" question in that it has a definite, singular answer. 

Finally, if not here, do you know where I can ask to have this question answered?

Comment: Maybe this page will be more accurate: https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "and it is not about...requesting external resources (questions should be specific and answerable on this site; external links are for references and supporting material)"

Comment: Thank you! Also, I do not think that section says what you think it says:

"requesting external resources (questions should be specific and answerable on this site; external links are for references and supporting material)"

I don't think this is saying its wrong to *name* external resources, only that external resources shouldn't be requested in order to answer your question. It says right there that "external links are for "references and supporting material". 

My question is both specific and answerable on this site. It doesn't require external references to be answered.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can ask this question without being gatekept? None of the search engines return any results. Certainly there must be a place where you can ask about music (that's not named music.stackexchange apparently), right?

Comment: Well, you'll see ;). The fact is that you are requesting a link for a particular material. Answers (if any) might be useful for you, but probably not for other people as this is something very specific, that's why I think it might get closed at some point but we'll see!

Comment: Understood, thank you for the advice I will use it in the future.

Comment: @jazzpiano: there might be a trick how you can formulate your question that someone will post you the link in his answer. (I'm not happy with this rule of not sharing resources because I have found a lot of interesting videos, books, theory links here! But I can understand the rule because this site would be overflown by requests for sheet music and surreptitious advertising).

Comment: How could this question reformulated that it would fit to the rules of this SE?

Comment: If it has been that long since it was in circulation you're going to have to luck out in order to find it, kind of like looking for an album that is out of print. I do offer a consolation prize, here is a link to several recordings of the song by different artists for you to enjoy: https://jazzhistoryonline.com/the-many-sounds-of-summertime/